# How to limit break-all to only long words?

Tags: javascript, css, word-wrap

I am trying to break very long words(some long uuid as well) in all `col` in bootstrap based template, but when I use the below style for all columns, it breaks everything(check bad breaking in example) even the places were normal wrapping at words worked perfectly(check expected breaking in example).

Is there a way I can use normal breaking wherever possible and revert to `break-all` only when it fails to do the trick? Javascript tricks are also welcome if that doesn't affect performance much.

I want normal breaking to work for space operated normal text and `break-all` to work if the text doesn't have any space and overflows. I wonder if this is even possible!

```css
div {
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  /* Mozilla */
  white-space: -hp-pre-wrap;
  /* HP printers */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  /* Opera 7 */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  /* Opera 4-6 */
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* CSS 2.1 */
  white-space: pre-line;
  /* CSS 3 (and 2.1 as well, actually) */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* IE */
  word-break: break-all;
}
.fifty {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  border: 10px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin: 1px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
h6 {
  clear: both;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fifty">aquickwhitefoxjumpsoverafrozendog</div>
<div class="fifty">A Quick White Fox Jumps Over A Frozen Dog</div>

<h6>Bad breaking at all places</h6>
<div class="fifty">StackOverflow is a privately held website, the flagship site of the StackExchangeNetwork, created in 2008 by Jeff-Atwood and Joel-Spolsky</div>

<h6>Expected breaking</h6>
<article class="fifty">StackOverflow is a privately held website, the flagship site of the StackExchangeNetwork, created in 2008 by Jeff-Atwood and Joel-Spolsky</article>
```

Comment: I need the exact same thing, and have the same problems...

Comment: @KlaymenDK I ended up using the below css, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
div {

  / These are technically the same, but use both /
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  / This is the dangerous one in WebKit, as it breaks things wherever /
  word-break: break-all;
  / Instead use this non-standard one: /
  word-break: break-word;

  / Adds a hyphen where the word breaks, if supported (No Blink) /
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;

}
.fifty {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  border: 10px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin: 1px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
h6 {
  clear: both;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fifty">aquickwhitefoxjumpsoverafrozendog</div>
<div class="fifty">A Quick White Fox Jumps Over A Frozen Dog</div>

<h6>Bad breaking at all places</h6>
<div class="fifty">StackOverflow is a privately held website, the flagship site of the StackExchangeNetwork, created in 2008 by Jeff-Atwood and Joel-Spolsky</div>

<h6>Expected breaking</h6>
<article class="fifty">StackOverflow is a privately held website, the flagship site of the StackExchangeNetwork, created in 2008 by Jeff-Atwood and Joel-Spolsky</article>
```