# Keeping text within div: Both newline, white-space and long words

Tags: javascript, html, overflow

Say I have the following string:

```
"This line should always break on newline \n, spaces if it is about to overflow and veryLongLinksThatDoNotFitInsideTheDiv"
```

I want it to break on:

- The \n (always)
- The white spaces (if it is about to overflow)
- The long word (if it does not fit on an entire single line)
- But preferably not on random small words that could fit on the next line ([How to limit break-all to only long words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138434/how-to-limit-break-all-to-only-long-words))

Based on [text flowing out of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196885/text-flowing-out-of-div), I tried:

```
    <div id="log" style="word-break: break-all"></div>
    <!-- <div id="log" style="word-wrap: break-word"></div> -->
    <!-- <div id="log" style="white-space: pre-line"></div> -->
    <!-- <div id="log" style="white-space: pre; word-break: break-all"></div> -->
```

But I can not get all 3 (nor 4) criteria met.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6kq14cfc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<div id="log" style="overflow-wrap: break-word;white-space: pre-wrap;"></div>
```

or

```
<div id="log" style="word-wrap: break-word;word-break: normal;white-space: pre-wrap;"></div>
```

Comment: Amit, thank you for your response. Unfortunately, at least in my Fiddle, the suggested solution does not address the newline character "\n". It does satisfy the other requirements.

Comment: @ThomasHubregtsen: To Confirm, place two \n simultaneously. You should see extra line break.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're answer lies in replacing "\n" with "<br />". HTML does not recognize new line characters - it needs the <br /> tag instead.

Comment: Thank you Rama Schneider. However, "white-space: pre-line" does accept \n as a new line. Unfortunately, the word breaking does not work in this case. (I put this also in the Fiddle to showcase). If possible, I do not want to change what my server sends/perform a replace on my data in the javascript.